# "order and degree of Btree"

Tags: tree, b-tree

What is relation between "order" and "degree" of B tree?

Different books used different convention.
If order =m then maximum key possible in a non root node is (m-1) (classic Data Structure ,Debasis Samanta,p-380)

If degree=t maximum node possible in a non root node is (2t-1)(Introduction to algorithm,by Cormen....,p-489)
If I merge this two then I can get
 m-1=2t-1=>m=2t (My idea,though it seems to be incorrect)
can anyone explain......Thanks.

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6799/b-tree-is-degree-and-order-both-are-the-same-thing-related-to-a-b-tree 
I have already seen this but this is not clearing my confusion.

Comment: Hint: indent code with four spaces.

Comment: This doesnt seem like a Python question.

Comment: similarly some time you may find different convention for height of tree some says root is at 0 some says at 1. So the thing understand concept.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan but i am finding this two concept contradict with each other

Comment: You can refer to my answer over here..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846377/what-is-the-difference-btw-order-and-degree-in-terms-of-tree-data-structure/40178066#40178066

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference btw "Order" and "Degree" in terms of Tree data structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846377/what-is-the-difference-btw-order-and-degree-in-terms-of-tree-data-structure)

Answer (score 0):

let the order of tree be m then:

max no of children = m
min no of children = cell(m/2)
if degree of tree is t then:

max no of key in a node is =2t-1;
min no of key in a node is =t-1;
Relation between degree and order:

Max no of key in a node = order of tree-1 or 2t-1=m-1